# Function to remove all the entries of specific duplicate number in the list

Tags: python-3.x

### **How to delete all the entries of specific number from list.**

However the way i followed below is just removing one time

```
newList = [1,2,3,4,5,2,6,7,5,8]
for num in newList:
    if newList.count(num) > 1:
        newList.remove(num)
print(newList)
```

### Result

[1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 8]

Comment: How about keeping instead of removing? `[i for i in newList if newList.count(i) == 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 issues with your code:

- you're modifying the list while iterating it. So you miss the next number (the "3" and the 2nd "2")
- `help(list.remove)` explicitly says it'll "remove first occurrence of value"

With a couple of print in your code, this becomes obvious:

```
newList = [1,2,3,4,5,2,6,7,5,8]
for num in newList:
    print (num)
    if newList.count(num) > 1:
        print('   -->removing')
        newList.remove(num)
print(newList)
```

outputs:

```
1
2
   -->removing
4
5
   -->removing
6
7
5
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
newList = [1,2,3,4,5,2,6,7,5,8,9,9,9,9]
l = []
for i,v in enumerate(newList):
    if v in l:
        l.pop(l.index(v))
    else:
         l.append(v)

print(l)
```

Comment: Its not working fine. I want to remove all the entries of duplicate number

Comment: thankyou. But i was looking for the built in function of python for this task may be it is not in existence.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```py
newList = [1,2,3,4,5,2,6,7,5,8]
for num in newList:
    if newList.count(num) > 1:
        for i in newList.count(num):
            newList.remove(num)
print(newList)
```